# Having a developer-specific configuration for Apache Ivy

Tags: java, ant, ivy

I'm using Apache Ivy to manage dependencies in the project with several developers. They will share most of the Ivy configuration, but some pieces (like corporate proxy username and password) should be developer-specific. I've created a reference file for everyone to place in the `~/.ivy2/ivysettings.xml` (this is where developer could specify his password), but cannot include it from the `ivy:configure` on Windows machines (Ivy does not expand environment variables there, and pointing to every developer's `~` is problematic).

Any suggestions on how could I allow developer-wide configuration in this setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The java property `user.home` performs the same role as the `~` from *NIX systems.

*(Note: On windows, the `USERPROFILE` environment variable fills this role)*

Ivy **can** work with java system properties, just use the `${user.home}` notation as you would in Ant.

References:

- http://www.mindspring.com/~mgrand/java-system-properties.htm
- http://www.wilsonmar.com/1envvars.htm#WinVars
- http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.0.0-rc1/settings.html